# Express.compress & mobile device

Tags: node.js, express, mobile

I'm trying to get express to show customers a different site based on their device. I.e. mobile users are served the mobile app and desktop users the web-app.

This is my code:

```
var express     = require('express'),
    app         = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var ua      = req.header('user-agent');
    // Check the user-agent string to identyfy the device.
    if(/mobile|iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|opera|mini|windows\sce|palm|smartphone|iemobile|ipad|android|android 3.0|xoom|sch-i800|playbook|tablet|kindle/i.test(ua)) {

        console.log("mobile");
        app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/mobile-app/www'));
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/mobile-app/www/index.html');

    } else {

        console.log("web");
        app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/web-app/www'));
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/web-app/www/index.html');

    }
});
```

Each app works fine. However, if I change the device using Chrome web-tools and then refresh, the other device won't load. I.e. if the first serve instance is on the web-app and I refresh on the mobile app...the mobile app won't work. If the first serve instance is on the mobile app, then refreshing onto the web app means this won't load.

Are there any ideas about how to do this better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because `app.use` is actually **adding middleware** that gets executed one after another. So the first time you open the web, you're saying '*from now on, serve the public files from this directory*'. Then you make the same thing when you open it form another kind of device.

Your *node server app* is running and it's just **one for all devices**. What you should do is provide content to the user depending on it's device. So it would be more like sending the proper html file (what you're doing right now), and **there** load resources from the specific folder. You might even pass the folder dynamically, like:

```
if (mobile) {
    res.render('template', { resourcesFolder: '/assets/mobile/ });
} else {
    res.render('template', { resourcesFolder: '/assets/desktop/ });
}
```

And there, in your template (use some template engine!) use it like:

```
<img src="{{ resourcesFolder}}image.jpg" />
```

This way, you can easily switch which image to show, depending on the `resourcesFolder` variable that you've just passed. And it can be different depending on user platform. So it's client dependent, not application dependent.